# upload featured image using custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads

I keep getting this error on specific posts that is created using custom post type.

> the server is busy or does not have enough resources. Uploading a
> smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels.

Some post of the same custom post type doesn't have this error but some does.

These are the steps that I have considered so far:

Themes & plugin testing  - I turned the plugin on/off to see if there are any changes but I still keep getting the error

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the error? Does that help?

Comment: I did, i am uploading small image less than 100kb, and still got the error @JacobPeattie